# How do I get rid of duplicates in an array?

Tags: objective-c

I'd like to do this without using NSSet. I know it's probably quicker but I'm trying to understand how arrays work. This is the mutable array I'm working with, it has duplicate values.

```
NSMutableArray *mainArray = @[@"a",@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"d"];
NSLog(@"mainArray = %@", mainArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (NSArray *)arrayWithUniqueObjectsFromArray:(NSArray *)array
{
    NSMutableArray *uniqueObjects = [NSMutableArray new];
    for(id obj in array) {
        if([uniqueObjects containsObject:obj] == NO) {
            [uniqueObjects addObject:obj];
        }
    }
    return uniqueObjects;
}
```

Comment: Some additional discussion: this solution works, but has O(N^2) complexity because `containsObject:` is O(n).  You could optionally use a hashtable or binary search to achieve O(log n) time.  (Of course, you could also just use NSMutableOrderedSet for this, which the OP does not want to use.)  http://www.objc.io/issue-7/collections.html has a good overview and more details.